# ¿Cómo abrir una pagina específica de un ViewPager tras volver de una activity?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

En mi actividad principal tengo un ViewPager con dos pestañas y un fragment en cada una, además tengo un menú overflow y al dar click en una opción me lanza otra actividad con un EditText y un botón, lo que quiero es que al apretar el botón vuelva a la actividad principal pero en la segunda página o en el segundo fragment pero si utilizo sólo un Intent por defecto me abre la primera página, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para volver directamente a la segunda página?

El código de mi actividad principal es este:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager vpMain;
private TabLayout tabs;

private ArrayList<String> nombres;
private ArrayList<String> favoritos;
private int[] pls1s;
private int[] fotos;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Añade la Action Bar:
    Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    //Inicializa UI:
    vpMain = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpMain);
    tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    nombres = new ArrayList<>();
    favoritos = new ArrayList<>();
    pls1s = new int[5];
    fotos = new int[5];

    if (actionBar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }

    iniciarTabs();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_opciones, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.imContacto:
            Intent contacto = new Intent(this, Contacto.class);
            startActivity(contacto);
            break;

        case R.id.imAbout:
            Intent about = new Intent(this, AcercaDe.class);
            startActivity(about);
            break;

        case R.id.imCuenta:
            Intent cuenta = new Intent(this, ConfigurarCuenta.class);
            startActivity(cuenta);
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public ArrayList<Fragment> iniciarFragments() {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    fragments.add(new ListaMascotas());
    fragments.add(new Perfil());

    return fragments;
}

public void iniciarTabs() {
    vpMain.setAdapter(new AdaptadorVPMain(getSupportFragmentManager(), iniciarFragments()));

    tabs.setupWithViewPager(vpMain);

    tabs.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mascotas);
    tabs.getTabAt(0).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_mascotas));

    tabs.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_perfil);
    tabs.getTabAt(1).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_perfil));

    tabs.setTabTextColors(R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.blanco);
}

}
```

Este es mi código de la actividad que se abre desde el menú:

```
public class ConfigurarCuenta extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextInputEditText etCuenta;
private Button btnCuenta;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_configurar_cuenta);

    //Añade la Action Bar:
    Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tbCuenta);
    setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    TextView tvTitulo = (TextView) actionBar.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
    tvTitulo.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.titulo_cuenta));

    agregarBtnBack();

    //Iniciar UI:
    etCuenta = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.etCuenta);
    btnCuenta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCuenta);
}

public void agregarBtnBack() {
    ImageButton back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent back = new Intent(ConfigurarCuenta.this, MainActivity.class);
            back.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(back);
        }
    });
}

public void clickGuardar(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(ConfigurarCuenta.this, getResources().getString(R.string.toast_conectar_cuenta),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent perfil = new Intent(ConfigurarCuenta.this, MainActivity.class);
    perfil.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(perfil);
}
}
```

Al botón le asigné el método clickGuardar en el archivo XML con la propiedad onClick.
También intenté tras iniciar mi actividad con el intent hacia la principal crear una instancia de mi fragment y luego llamar a su método onResume() pero no funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

En vez de simplemente abrir el Activity, a mayores le envías un código, el que tú quieras, que ese Activity te devolverá, de esta forma podrás identificar que vienes de ese Activity y abrir la página que quieras. Es simple.

Dónde abres el nuevo Activity, en vez de `startActivity` haces:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, CODIGO);
```

Dónde `intent` es el Intent que quieres abrir (el de la nueva Activity en este caso) y `CODIGO` es el código que quieras enviarle, es de tipo entero y puedes poner lo que quieras, 4400 por ejemplo.

Se abrirá el nuevo Activity y al cerrarse te devolverá ese `CODIGO`. Para recibirlo simplemente sobreescribes el método `onActivityResult` en el primer Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Compruebas si el código es el que tú le has enviado (pueden recibirse otros)
    if (requestCode == CODIGO) {
        // Abres la página que quieras
        vpMain.setCurrentItem(1); // 1 para ir a la segunda página ya que empiezan en 0
    }                
}
```

Tienes más información en la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html#ReceiveResult)

Comment: La verdad es que tu solución me parece muy buena, muchas gracias, pero tengo un problema, depurando me di cuenta de que nunca se ejecuta el método onActivityResult, no se qué pueda causar que no se ejecute; por ahora lo solucioné mandando el código como extra a la activity pero tienes alguna idea de por qué el método no se ejecuta?

Comment: Pues así de primeras no se decirte, puede ser por varios motivos, buscando por la red puedes ver de más gente que le pasa esto y cómo han podido solucionarlo.